# How to get users associated with a team in Liferay

Tags: liferay, liferay-6, portlet, liferay-7, liferay-7.1

I Need to fetch Team associated with the group in Liferay.

- First I created the User
- Then I made a group
- Then I made a Team
- The team is associated with the group
- so I fetch the user, who is login
- then I fetch the group which is associated with it
- Now I am not able to fetch the team from the group

Need Some Help

I do this thing but, from this, I got all the team which is created, I need a team which is associated with a specific group

```
long groupId = themeDisplay.getLayout().getGroupId();
List<Team> teamGroup=TeamLocalServiceUtil.getGroupTeams(groupId);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I Got Solution

You can Fetch Team associated with the Group

```
    //you have to first find user group id than pass it simply

    TeamLocalServiceUtil.getUserGroupTeams(userGroupId));
```